# Vue 3 watch being called before value is fully updated

Tags: vue.js, vuex, vuejs3, vuex4

I'm working on my first Vue 3 (and therefore vuex 4) app coming from a pretty solid Vue 2 background.

I have an component that is loading data via vuex actions, and then accessing the store via a returned value in `setup()`

```
  setup() {
    const store = useStore();
    const fancy = computed(() => store.state.fancy);
    return { fancy };
  },
```

`fancy` here is a deeply nested object, which I think might be important.

I then want to run a function based on whenever than value changes, so I have set up a `watch` in my `mounted()` lifecycle hook

```
 watch(
      this.fancy,
      (newValue) => {
        for (const spreadsheet in newValue) {
          console.log(Object.keys(newValue[spreadsheet].data))
          setTimeout(()=>{
            console.log(Object.keys(newValue[spreadsheet].data))
          },500)
          ...
```

I tried using the new `onMounted()` hook in setup and `watchEffect` and `store.watch` instead, but I could not get  watch/watchEffect to reliably trigger in the onMounted hook, and watchEffect never seemed to update based on my computed store value. If you have insight into this, that would be handy.

My real issue though is that my watcher gets called seemingly before the value is updated. For instance my code logs out `[]` for the first set of keys, and then a half second later a full array. If it was some kind of progressive filling in of the data, then I would have expected the watcher to be called again, with a new `newValue`. I have also tried. all the permutations of `flush`, `deep`, and `immediate` on my watcher to no avail. `nextTick()`s also did not work. I think this must be related to my lack of understanding in the new reactivity changes, but I'm unsure how to get around it and adding in a random delay in my app seems obviously wrong.

Thank you.

Comment: could you enrich this [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/using-vuex-4-modules-in-vue-3-with-typescript-7ygvy) in order to allow us to debug it ?

Comment: Thank you for setting that up, I was not familiar with that tool. My minimum example seems to work as expected, so I will keep bisecting to try and find the issue.

Comment: as a third paramater `{immediate:true}` does the job for me most of the time.